# C# DynamicObject: Is there a way to access properties by index?

Tags: c#, dynamic, indexing

Is there a way to access the properties of a dynamic object by index?

```
List<dynamic> list = _dataStagingManager.GetStatusList(consoleSearch);
foreach (var row in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(row[1]);
}
```

In this example, the property name of row[0] is different depending on the results from a stored procedure column alias.

Comment: What kind of dynamic object is it? Where do you get it from?

Comment: Initially, I was using the general dynamic object type DynamicObject. It does turn out the dynamic object returned by Dapper does extend this object and includes a Keys and Values property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, that's not possible. For example, you could create a dynamic object that has every possible property:

```
class AnythingGoes : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = binder.Name;
        return true;
    }
}
```

There is a chance you will be able to get the list of properties. If the dynamic object is actually normal object (one that does not implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`), normal reflection will work fine.

If the object actually is dynamic (implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`), you could try calling [`GetDynamicMemberNames()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicmetaobject.getdynamicmembernames.aspx) on the `DynamicMetaObject` returned from [`GetMetaObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider.getmetaobject.aspx). But, as the example above shows, this is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no. Unlike runtime objects (which have an iterable collection of their members that can easily be reflected/queried against) dynamic objects, by default, have no such collection. They can be implemented in any way that allows their members to be accessed by name. There is no idea of indices with dynamic objects, provided you don't choose to implement them yourself.

If you wanted to, you could override the [`TryGetIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetindex.aspx) method on your dynamic type to provide indexing support.

Comment: Of course. `Unfortunately, no` doesn't seem to be correct. It all depends on how you code your dynamic object. See my answer

Comment: Yes. But I think the OP was looking for a *general-purpose* way to iterate the members of a dynamic object (not one he controls, perhaps) which is patently impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with [Dapper Dot Net](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) but after a short look at it, it looks as if it is returning anonymous types as dynamic objects. You can look at those as POCOs (plain old CLR objects) meaning that they are classes with individual named properties, probably not implementing any kind of indexer which you would needed to access fields by index.

You could try using Reflection to achieve something similar:

```
foreach (dynamic propInfo in row.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", propInfo.Name, propInfo.GetValue(row, null));
}
```

I'm not sure you'll get the properties in the same order the stored procedure is returning them, though.

Comment: In your example `row.GetType()` returns null.

Answer (score -2):

If `row`'s runtime type is has an integer indexer, then your code should be fine as is.

Comment: Can you please give an example of this? Basically, I have an object of type List<dynamic>, which contains a data result set from a stored procedure mapped by Dapper Dot Net.

Comment: I am not familiar with Dapper Dot Net.  But, for example, if the row is an ADO.NET DataRow, then the expression row[0] will be dispatched at runtime to the indexer, which will return the value stored in the first column (and row[1] the second, etc.)